# Create an array and get the lowest and highest value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following markup:

```
<figure  data-item="0"> ... </figure>
<figure  data-item="1"> ... </figure>
<figure  data-item="2"> ... </figure>
<figure  data-item="3"> ... </figure>
<figure  data-item="4"> ... </figure>
...
```

And so on.

What I need is get the highest and lowest data-item value.

I start with this:

```
var arr = [3, 36, 66, 2, 7];
max = 0;

$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (v > max) max = v; 
});

console.log(max);
```

But I don't know how to create an array like that

Comment: So, what have you tried?  We're not just gonna give you the answer.  As a hint though, you can start with [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: Unordered, which appears to be ordered in your example.

Comment: @Gabe is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4U87/)

```
var myArray = $('figure').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('item');
}).get();

var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, myArray);
var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, myArray);
```

Comment: this script is printing 'Infinity' for me

Comment: the jsfiddle works, provide then your relevant code. I think you are not casting value to number. But as data API auto cast value to corresponding type, i don't know really what are you doing???

Comment: you are correct. I found an error in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get the min and max values

```
var min = 999;
var min = 0;

$("figure").each()
{
    var value = $(this).data("item");
    if(value < min) min = value;
    if(value > max) max = value;
}

alert(min);
alert(max);
```

Comment: But the min max values will be get from a database.

Comment: Then it's unclear. Do you have the values stored in DOM or not?

Comment: @user2433958: Then what was the point of the `<figure>` elements?  What is your *real* question?  What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To make an array from your elements, you can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
var arr = $('figure').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('item');
}).get();

var max = 0;

$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (v > max) max = v; 
});

console.log(max);
```